# DNX dependency conflict "The type 'CultureInfo' exists in both 'System.Globalization' and 'mscorlib'"?

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I have started a new project in Visual Studio 2015 using DNX SDK version 1.0.0-beta6. I need to use the class `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` in my class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public CultureInfo Culture { get; private set; }

        // ...etc.
    }
}
```

I was prompted to add a reference to `System.Globalization` which I did using Nuget.  After that, I got the following error:

> The type 'CultureInfo' exists in both 'System.Globalization,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Global.json

```
{
  "sources": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Baz.Domain.Model": ""
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Clearly I have a dependency problem, but I am uncertain how these are resolved with the new DNX. Surely if the reference was already present in `mscorlib` I shouldn't have been prompted to add a reference, and surely if it wasn't I should not be getting the second error. How can I resolve this dependency problem?

Comment: You should show the `global.josn` and the `project.json`.

Comment: Is this a compile-time error?  Can it be as easy as using the full names to distinguish between the two classes?  (e.g. `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` rather than just `CultureInfo` ?)

Comment: @adv12 Yes, it is a compile-time error but no, the classes are both `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` but different versions. I tried this anyway, but to no effect.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have added this code. Note that I did not manually modify this - I added `System.Globalization` using Nuget.

Comment: Which Clr Type have you chosen? You can check it from Start dropdown.

Comment: How about the dependency `TransitApi.Domain.Model`?  Does it require `System.Globalization` as a direct dependency.  It should just be used for anything running .net core.

Comment: Thanks @DavidD I think this was on the right track. I have posted my solution as an answer, if you can improve on this I would be happy to accept yours over mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem did indeed lie in the project.json files, but those of the other projects in my solution.

I had targeted "dotnet" instead of "dnx451" in my other projects which was the default when creating new projects. I changed all frameworks in each project.json file as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { }
},
```

I then removed all references to .NET Core packages (System.*) under "dependencies".

This resolved the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by removing the reference to `System.Data.Common` (which was the source of the reference to `System.Globalization`). I don't know what will happen if I end up actually needing `System.Globalization`, but I'll cross that bridge later, I suppose.